# Fetch max value column with rows condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to fetch the max value according to 2 columns in a pandas dataframe. I managed to do this according to 1 column but not 2.

For 1 column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": list("ABABCD"), "value": np.arange(6)})
maxes = df.groupby(["name"]).agg("max")
df["maxvalue"]=df["name"].apply(lambda x: maxes.loc[x])
```

```
>>> df
   name value maxvalue
0   A     0     2
1   B     1     3
2   A     2     2
3   B     3     3
4   C     4     4
5   D     5     5
```

For 2 columns, I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": list("ABABCD"),"name2": list("MNOMNO"), "value": np.arange(6)})
maxes = df.groupby(["name","name2"]).agg("max")
df["maxvalue"]=df[["name","name2"]].apply(lambda x: maxes.loc[x])
```

How can this be done for multiple columns?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) instead of `agg`. Using one or two columns is exactly the same, for two columns it will be as follows:

```
df["maxvalue"] = df.groupby(["name", "name2"]).transform("max")
```